# how to host live stream video

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

Using jwplayer with html5 users can watch videos online..
just put the source where the video file is located,, and the users can play the video that easy..

i also tried to put a live stream source, as i remember it is rts://sampledomain.com/video.mp4, 
then jwplayer easily play that mp4 file..

my question is
how can i host this kind of file "rts://sampledomain.com/video.mp4" using my web camera or hypercam3 as my video recorder.. and send it to jwplayer so the users can play live stream in the browser using jwplayer..

any hint are appreciated, but thank you very much for step by step tutorials..

Answer (score 0):

You must use a mediastreamer.
Many solution exists.  You can use program as vlc or mplayer to create the stream, or prefer a solution as RED5 (http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/red5), available for most of linux distribution.

Hope it helps.